# How to deploy through AWS codeploy using composer when a dependency is in a private repository

Tags: git, bash, amazon-web-services, composer-php, aws-code-deploy

So I'm new to AWS Codedeploy, I have it successfully deploying with one little issue, every time I add to my deploy script composer update I get this lovely little message "Permission denied (publickey)".

Now when I run composer update as ubuntu user it runs fine, my key is setup in the private repository fine, I have made sure that the bash file is run as ubuntu.

So how do other people setup their code deployments to work with private composer repositories? Sorry if there is something obvious but I am very baffled.

If someone can answer you would make one developer very happy.

Comment: CodeDeploy runs as `root`, so the `root` user needs to have access to your key. Try adding it to `/root/.ssh/` and see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work as the SSH agent hasn't started

Comment: Your key has a passphrase on it? Then I'd generate a dedicated [deploy key](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) without a passphrase for deployment.

Comment: Sorry noob question but how do you setup a deploy key to be used on your server with codedeploy.

Comment: A deploy key is just a regular SSH key. Generate a new key for `root` and add it to your repository as a deploy key (GitHub, Bitbucket, and GitLab all support this) or otherwise make sure it's granted access to the repo in question.

Comment: Works like a charm. Happy composerage

Answer (score 0):

Use a Deployment Key on the root user.

Answer (score 0):

The way I had it set up for my application that has multiple private composer packages is to create an artifact of my application then deploy that via CodeDeploy.

A summary of what I do

- On my CI machine (Jenkins or my local), run composer. This machine will already have the appropriate access to the repos.
- Tar Ball/Zip up my application together with the corresponding vendor folder created by composer - this is my deploy artifact
- Save that artifact to S3
- Have CodeDeploy begin a deploy with that artifact in S3 as my source

This method is more scalable especially when you are deploying to >1 server

- avoids adding private keys on your server(s)
- avoids your servers from running composer individually